# Auto-condition and Auto-conditioning

Tags: science

In the context of X-Ray imaging, to **auto-condition**, is to prepare the X-Ray source so that it achieves a stable operating voltage and produces a steady image. You may also use the verb in the form **auto-conditioning** to indicate that the system is busy performing this task (as it may take several minutes).

If I'm showing this feature in the UI of an App connected to an X-Ray system, and I would like to show a button to the user so they start to "Auto-condition" and another message to show that the system is "Auto-conditionning" what would be the best ways to describe this?:

---

Auto-condition = Auto-conditionner

Auto-conditioning = Auto-conditionnement

Examples:

... to auto-condition the system do the following:

- *... pour auto-conditionner le système, procédez comme suit:*

X-Ray auto-conditionning will be executed ...

- *L'auto-conditionnement des rayons X sera exécuté ...*

The X-ray auto-contitionning process involves: ...

- *Le processus d'auto-conditionnement des rayons X implique: ...*

---

or

Auto-condition = Conditionner auto

Auto-conditionnement = Conditionnement auto

Examples:

... to auto-condition the system do the following:

- *... pour conditionner auto le système, procédez comme suit:*

X-Ray auto-conditionning will be executed ...

- *Le conditionnement auto des rayons X sera exécuté ...*

The X-ray auto-contitionning process involves: ...

- *Le processus de conditionnement auto des rayons X implique: ...*

or any other idea / better translation?

Comment: is the term "auto-conditioning" a standard term for this operation in English? If yes, it may be that a different translation is the de-facto French standard. If not, then you could actually use any very generic term like "Opération préliminaires", "Préparation de l'environnement" or simply choose your very own wording assuming you'll anyway need to explain somewhere what lies behind the word.

Comment: Apparently, only a pronominal form of the verb exists; https://www.cordial.fr/dictionnaire/definition/autoconditionner.php, https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/auto-conditionner ; I'll have to change my answer somewhat.

Comment: The only company that I can find that uses the term just like that in English is NIKON. And I find nothing at all in French with that literal translation. So, something is very off.

Comment: Here are the top ten manufacturers of x-ray machines: https://www.hospitalmanagement.net/features/featuremedical-imaging-technology-diagnostic-device-manufacturers/ I suggest you go and read some manuals and see how they say it and not rely solely on Nikon. Try and look at English-speaking ones like GE.

Comment: The more I read, the more I think this is translation from Japanese...but not standard English terminology. The only reason I have posted three comments is due to the dangers and hazards of this type of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I**     *The first set of options is the best choice; there is a problem in the form of the verb, which in French is a pronominal verb and  a small error in a tense. For that reason the verb must be replaced by the noun. Another problem is that apparently this concept has not been used for anything else than human beings.*

First example

... to auto-condition the system do the following => ... **pour l'auto-conditionnement du système, procédez comme suit** :

In the second example the "futur proche" must be used instead of the "futur"; however, the resulting form while correct is not of a usual model for short indications.

X-Ray auto-conditionning will be executed …=> **L'auto-conditionnement des rayons X va être exécuté …**

The third is  right.

The X-ray auto-contitionning process involves : …=> **Le processus d'auto-conditionnement des rayons X implique : …**

Added example

The system is undergoing auto-conditioning => **Auto-conditionnement en cours** or **Le système s'auto-conditionne**

**II**     *The second set is not correct because there does not exist in French any alternative syntax involving the separation of a prefix from the root word.*

**III**     *D'autres possibilités*

... to auto-condition the system do the following => ... **Marche à suivre pour l'auto-conditionnement du système** :

X-Ray auto-conditionning will be executed …=> **Auto-conditionnement des rayons X**

The X-ray auto-contitionning process involves : …=> **Le processus d'auto-conditionnement des rayons X entraine : …**

Comment: The English is not right so I don't see how you can invent French from that. There is only a single hit for this...from Nikon.